# Java code replaceall method replaces a string with blank value?

Tags: java

The Below java code replaces all the character in string variable BusDetails with blank even though i don't see a (. dot) for the method to replace it. Why ?

Output = _BusDetails

```
String BusDetails = " BUS_12_UFV_BOURQUIN_COMMUTER_TO_UFV";

String table_UniqueBusNameTimings = BusDetails.replaceAll(".", "")+"_BusTimings";

System.out.println("TableName: "+table_UniqueBusNameDetails);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replaceAll` treats its first argument as a *regular expression*, and in regular expressions a dot matches *any* single character except a newline.

To replace one *fixed* string with another you should use the [`replace` method that takes two `CharSequence` parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead - despite its name, this method does in fact replace *all* occurrences of the first `CharSequence` with the second one.

```
String table_UniqueBusNameTimings = BusDetails.replace(".", "")+"_BusTimings";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape that meta character

```
String table_UniqueBusNameTimings = BusDetails.replaceAll("\\.", "")+"_BusTimings";
```

See how escapes works in java

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape the period, like this:

```
    String BusDetails = " BUS_12_UFV_BOURQUIN_COMMUTER_TO_UFV";

    String table_UniqueBusNameTimings = BusDetails.replaceAll("\\.", "")+"_BusTimings";

    System.out.println("TableName: "+table_UniqueBusNameTimings);
```